# What's missing here? (DB1) LED bar

Tags: pcb

Can anyone help me?
This is a visibly tampered LED strip and it's missing this component DB1, which I think is a diode but I don't know exactly what it is.
The LED strip is powered with 220v.

[image]

Comment: English is required on this site - please translate.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's a bridge rectifier. Something like an [HD-06](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/products_inactive_data/ds17003.pdf) (available from other suppliers). but check the dimensions. Also the traces may be damaged so they may have to be jumpered to the correct places.

The fuse (white color device) should also be checked.

Comment: I suppose it is a MB10F chip also cause there is no diode sign on the LED bar but there is a rectifier simbol